# Reactjs form values is displayed through state but when I submitted a form field and value not submitted

Tags: reactjs, validation, touch-event, react-props

I have implement redux form and get data from props and changed props to state in componentWillReceiveProps, value displaying in my field but when i submit a form without interacting then form value not submitted.

```
<Field
name="standardDistanceBetween"
type="text"
onChange={this.onInputChange}
data={this.state.standardDistanceBetween}
label="Distance Between Shaft Ends"
component={renderInput1}
/>
```

I expect the output when form submitted without interacting the fields the value will submitted.

Answer (score 0):

In your submit function console state variable to check if state has value or not, if you are using formik onSubmit function you will get your input fields data in "values" parameter 
like below

```
onSubmit ={(values) => {
    console.log(values)
}}
```

Comment: Not helpful, data is not displayed on the console.

Comment: I hope you are implementing above code in Formik Tag